# Fill out both Question and Answer field In Enquirer CLI Prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, input, command-line-interface

I'm using the [enquirer](https://github.com/enquirer/enquirer) package to prompt users for input in my Nodejs CLI application.

Currently, I am using the built-in [form](https://github.com/enquirer/enquirer#form-prompt) prompt for input like so -

```
const prompt = new Form({
  name: 'user',
  message: 'Please provide the following information:',
  choices: [
    { name: 'First Name', message: 'First Name'},
    { name: 'Last Name', message: 'Last Name'},
    { name: 'Date of Birth', message: 'Date of Birth'}
  ]
});
```

This works well for forms with pre-defined fields ie. -

```
Please provide the following information:    

Field1: _______ 

Field2: _______ 

Field3: _______
```

but I now would like to present the user with a custom field, with the ability to edit both the question and answer of the field ie. -

```
________: _______
```

Ideally, this custom field would be presented alongside other predefined fields like so -

```
Field1: _______ 

Field2: _______ 

Field3: _______ 

______: _______
```

Which the user could fill out like so -

```
Field1: Answer1

Field2: Answer2 

Field3: Answer3 

NewField: Answer4
```

And this would return an Object similar to -

```
{
  "Field1": "Answer1",
  "Field2": "Answer2",
  "Field3": "Answer3",
  "NewField": "Answer4",
}
```

Enquirer does support [custom prompts](https://github.com/enquirer/enquirer#-custom-prompts), but I'm struggling to get my head around exactly how I might go about implementing something like this.

Alternatively, I am open to using another module (ie. Inquirer) if this type of prompt can be implemented easier using a different package.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `Editable Prompt` (it extends the `Form Prompt` to add the functionality you're looking for). You press `Ctrl+n` to add a new item.

See the [examples here](https://github.com/enquirer/enquirer/tree/master/examples/editable)... the simplest one is [add choice](https://github.com/enquirer/enquirer/blob/master/examples/editable/prompt-add-choice.js)

The main difference from your use case is that when hitting `Ctrl+n`, the user is prompted for the name, then the value can be entered.

You can also use the `header` or `footer` options passed to the prompt constructor to provide additional instructions to your users.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was after!